# Can I modify this FET board to the ground leg instead of the VCC leg (see image)

Tags: fet

Please see if the modification I have made to the FET switch board looks workable. See image attached.

And I know it doesn't look like but the Drain is connected to VPP in the modified schematic.

[image]

EDIT: Maybe this  Pchannel circuit would do it?

[image]

Comment: Why do you want to change it?

Comment: With the unmodified circuit you turn the FET on hard and get nearly the full supply across the load. With the modified circuit you can't get the full voltage because you need Vgs to turn it on. If you need the load to be in the negative side you can use a similar circuit but with a P channel FET and pulling the gate down instead of up to switch it on.

Comment: Thanks Warren - see the new circuit I posted which is what you suggest.  Keven I need to change the circuit to high side because I want to switch circuits that have external grounds, the unmodified version will not shut off those types of circuits. It will work only on isolated circuits (like  motors or lights).

Comment: Yes that would do it

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you plan to connect your load at 1-1 and 1-2, the answer is no. You will not develop enough gate/source voltage to drive any amount of power through your load.

EDIT - Let's assume your VPP is +5 volts, and your optocoupler can turn fully ON. That is, when it is ON, the voltage across it is zero. This won't be true, but the data sheet is silent on this, and it makes the analysis simpler.

Now keep in mind that, from the FET data sheet, The $V_GS(th)$ (Gate turn-on threshold is in the range or 2 to 4 volts. In the worst case, assume it is 4 volts.

If your optocoupler is driven ON, the FET will only be on for load voltages of 1 volt, since the gate is held at VPP(5 volts) and the source is 4 volts lower in order to allow current to flow into the load.

Comment: I modified the drawing for clarity Do you still think that their will not be enough current ? If not, can you explain.

Comment: @Sam: The problem is not the current, it's the voltage. You will have trouble pushing the voltage high enough to turn on the FET.

Comment: @Sam - see edit.